# Checking if the UNIX timestamp stored in MySQL DB is this weeks or this months?

Tags: mysql

I have a `MySQL` DB, and in one of the tables I have stored the time in which the content was submitted its in the form of a UNIX timestamp, the column is called `content_time`. Below are two pseudo examples of queries to demonstrate what I'm trying to accomplish, just not sure how to go by doing this (although I understand I will need do some some comparisons between the current and stored timestamps within the `WHERE` clause):

```
SELECT * FROM content 
WHERE content_time = THIS WEEKS 
(the content was posted at any time/day within the current week)

SELECT * FROM content 
WHERE content_time = THIS MONTHS 
(the month and year from content_time match with the current)
```

Appreciate all help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See MySQL's [Date and Time Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html), specifically `FROM_UNIXTIME()`, `WEEK()` and `MONTH()`. Keep in mind that when checking is it the same week or month you probably also want to check is it the same year.

Another option is to generate start and end timestamps for the time range youre intrested in (ie timestamp for the beginning of the week and for the end of the week) and then use `WHERE(content_time BETWEEN start AND end)`

Comment: okay great (I've used your first option), what is the timezone MySQL Date and Time functions use, I'm guessing its GMT?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea but my quess is servers' (OS) timezone. You can use MySQL's `CONVERT_TZ()` function to convert between timezones.